# Should I split my database into current year's data and all past year's data?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, partition

I am trying to configure a SQL server to run as efficiently as possible, while maintaining clean DB development standards.  I have tables with millions of records, and sometimes have to join 5+ tables in a single query for Tableau Reports.

My question is whether it would be operationally more efficient to replicate the DB that I currently use and move all data for past seasons into it, since that data is only rarely used in reports.  So my current DB would only have FY2018 data and the historical DB would contain FY2017, FY2016, FY2015, and FY2014.

Would this be worth the hassle and potential maintenance headaches?  I don't know if it's worth it, or unneeded in the absence of inefficient queries.

Thanks!

Comment: [Consider partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017) and proper indexing before you consider tossing this data into cold storage. Although, if it is truly "rarely used" then it's not so terrible to hide it away in another table. Call it "Archiving" ;) Just be ready to put 2018 into the same table next year. As long as that doesn't seem like too much maintenance, then it's reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.   What do you do at the end of the year?

What you should do is create an index on year and then when they user puts a criteria on year (eg = current year) it will run just as fast as if it had been split.

Comment: Thanks Hogan!  I will go with the indexing approach in that case.

Comment: Hey Hogan, is there a chance that indexing as opposed to partitioning would degrade SQL performance for JOIN and WHERE statements?

Comment: @Mitchatwork -- well when you have an index you have to do work on inserts -- so that could be a problem if you have a lot of inserts into your DB.  Also if you don't run statistics regularly and your data shape changes this could cause the index and compiler to make bad choices.  -- Probably more but those are the first two ways that come to mind.